# JavaScript, issue with object variables being declared NaN

Tags: javascript

I have made the following object in javascript :

```
var gr = {
    SIZE : 30,
    NO_X : (window.innerWidth / this.SIZE),
    NO_Y : (window.innerHeight / this.SIZE),
    drawGrid : function(){
        console.log(`NO_X : ${this.NO_X}`);
        console.log(`NO_Y : ${this.NO_Y}`);

        //
        //grid drawing function here
        //
    }
}
```

when I call the drawGrid function, the console log statements return the values of both NO_X and NO_Y as NaN, I would like them to equal the screen width / SIZE .

If I use window.innerWidth outside of the object it works as expected.

Sorry if the answer is obvious I am pretty new to programming in javascript.

thanks!

Comment: `this.SIZE` is probably `undefined`

Comment: The `this` symbol does not refer to the under-construction object. There is no way to do that. (in an object initializer)

Comment: @Thomas `this` is correct in the `drawGrid()` function, but not in the `this.SIZE` reference.

Comment: @Terry that's why I changed the comment

Comment: Can you please post your full code

Comment: @Terry and Thomas were correct, changing the this.Size to the number 30 solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `NO_X` and `NO_Y` to [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead like:

```
get NO_X() {
    return window.innerWidth / this.SIZE
  },
  get NO_Y() {
    return window.innerHeight / this.SIZE
  },
```

and then you should be able to access `this.NO_X` and `this.NO_Y` inside `drawGrid` properly. In this way you can draw grid with any size you want, instead of a fixed size `30`.

```js
var gr = {
  SIZE: 30,
  get NO_X() {
    return window.innerWidth / this.SIZE
  },
  get NO_Y() {
    return window.innerHeight / this.SIZE
  },
  drawGrid: function() {
    console.log(`NO_X : ${this.NO_X}`);
    console.log(`NO_Y : ${this.NO_Y}`);
  }
}

// Draw grid with size 30
gr.drawGrid()


// Draw grid with size 20
gr.SIZE = 20
gr.drawGrid()
```